# Windows Azure for simulation

Tags: azure, simulation, montecarlo

We are thinking of using Windows Azure for simulation. ~100 VM nodes each working on it's problem set and reporting back the result to a Master node.

I have created VM instances from the web UI. In order for this to work, we would need to use Azure API to bring servers up and shut them down once they are done.

Does anyone have any experience with something like this? I am looking for advise, gotchas etc.

thanks.

Comment: @BrentDaCodeMonkey we have looked into it. The issue is, the simulation was built using a in-house dist. grid system. We are just looking to expand to cloud for compute resources on cheap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You sure can do it and I have helped other to make it happen on hundreds on nodes. Take a look at Windows Azure Rest API to configure your role as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee460799.aspx). While others may have other idea, I think the general steps would be as below:

1. Create a master machine or a webrole to manage your roles using REST API
2. Create a worker role instance and use it to clone multiple instances as if needed
3. Use REST API to start and shutdown worker role along with update the instance count when in need
4. Use [Azure Boot Strapper](http://bootstrap.codeplex.com/) to bootstrap the VM depend on your requirement

Azure REST based Service Management API can work from a web app or a standalone app, so you can also have a web role to make it happen from anywhere in world. This way you don't need any on premise components at all as it will be totally cloud solution. If you need any help on creating web role I sure can help.

Answer (score 1):

You can provision Virtual Machines using [Service Management REST API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee460799.aspx) (there's also [a managed API on NuGet](http://nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.ServiceManagement.Library)).

But in your case you might want to consider using Cloud Services (PaaS). With Cloud Services you simply build your application, you package it and deploy it. Then using the portal or the management API you can simply configure the number of instances. There is even a command line tool ([csmanage.exe](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/Windows-Azure-CSManage-e3f1882c)) which allows you to to change the number of instances through the service configuration.